# Regular Expression For Numbers and Special Characters

Tags: javascript

I need few Regular Expression which should validate these;

**1) Org Name :**

abc                         --- **`Valid`**

abc123                  ---**`Valid`**

abc_hyd               ---**`Valid`**

123                         -- **`InValid`**

____                         **`InValid`**

@#$%%%)(*&        **`InValid`**

**2) Org Number  :**

123                         -- **`Valid`**

abc123                  --- **`Valid`**

abc                         --- **`InValid`**

____                         **`InValid`**

@#$%%%)(*&        **`InValid`**

abc_hyd               ---**`InValid`**

Comment: Unless you have very precise specs for what kind of string you're trying to capture, I don't think anybody can give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex: `(?=([\w]+))(?=[^\d])`

Example:

```
/(?=([\w]+))(?=[^\d])/g.exec("abs123") // return ["", "abs123"]
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `/[^\d]+[\w]+/g`?

Comment: It is not working, i want a regexp which will accept only characters or the combination of characters like  abc -- Valid abc@123 valiad but @#$$@ it should not accept. Please provide some solution on this.